# I tried two approaches and gained the different conclusions of judging the stability of the transfer function of the system

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform, transfer-function, stability, time-domain

We want to judge whether the system is stable or not.

Given the below transfer function.

$$ H\left( z  \right) =\frac{\left( 1+2 z^{-1}  \right) }{\left( 2+z^{-1}  \right) }   $$

$$ H\left( z  \right) =2-\frac{3}{2+z^{-1} }   $$

$$  2+\frac{-3}{2+z^{-1} } $$

$$S:=\frac{-3}{2+z^{-1} }$$

$$ S ~~\text{is the sum of each element of the geometric sequence.}  $$

$$ -3 ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{initial term}  $$

$$ z^{-1} ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{common ratio}  $$

$$ i \geq1 \rightarrow \text{ith term} = -3 \cdot \left( z^{-1}  \right) ^{i-1}  $$

$$ = -3 \cdot z^{1-i} =-3 \cdot z^{-0}~,~-3z^{-1}~,~-3 z^{-2} ~,~ \cdot\cdot\cdot     $$

$$ H\left( z^{}   \right) =\sum_{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  } h\left[ n \right]  z^{-n}   $$

$$ \sum_{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  } \left( 2 \delta\left[n  \right]  +\left( -3 \right) u\left[ n  \right]  \right)z^{-n}     $$

$$\displaystyle \therefore ~~ h\left[ n \right] =2 \delta\left[n  \right]  +\left( -3 \right) u\left[ n  \right]  $$

$$  \sum_{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  } \left| h\left[ n \right]  \right|    $$

$$ = \sum_{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  } \left|  2 \delta\left[n  \right]  +\left( -3 \right) u\left[ n  \right]\right|  = \infty  $$

$$  \therefore ~~ ~~\text{The system is unstable.}~~   $$

However from the another approach,

$$ H\left( z  \right) =2-\frac{3}{2+z^{-1} }   $$

$$ = \frac{2 \left( 2+ z^{-1}  \right) -3}{2+z^{-1} }   $$

$$2+z^{-1}  = 0  $$

$$  2+\frac{1}{z^{} } =0  $$

$$  \frac{1}{z^{} } =-2  $$

$$  z=-\frac{1}{2} =-0.5 ~~ \leftarrow~~ ~~\text{pole}~~   $$

$$  ~~\text{Since }~~ \left| \text{pole}  \right|  =\left| -0.5 \right| =\left| 0.5 \right| <1 ~~\text{is held, the system is stable.}~~  $$

Why the different concolusions were gained?

What I've been missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is stable. Your mistake is in the application of the formula for the geometric series:

$$\begin{align}-\frac{3}{2+z^{-1}}&=-\frac32\frac{1}{1+\frac12z^{-1}}\\&=-\frac32\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac12\right)^nz^{-n}\end{align}$$

Hence, the system's impulse response is

$$h[n]=2\delta[n]-\frac32\left(-\frac12\right)^nu[n]$$